# Чистый api telegram или библиотеки?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на чем пишут популярные, высокопосещаемые боты телеграм на python.
С использованием официального апи или через библиотеки?
Лучше использовать библиотеки или официальное апи?

Если библиотеки, то какие на данный момент актуальные, какие умерли или умирают? (aiogram, pyTelegramApi, aiogr, python-telegram-bot или другие)
Понравилась связка pytelegramapi +flask, но они не асинхронные, как я понял, выдержит эта связка нагрузки, к примеру одновременное обращение 1000 чел? Или затупит?
Бот будет записывать в базу и читать из нее, так же собирать информацию с других сайтов и записывать в базу.

Если есть примеры высоконагруженных ботов на какой-то из библиотек, с удовольствием посмотрю.

Хотелось бы чтоб написанный бот служил долго и безотказно.
Перелопатил кучу информацию, так чтоб четко ответили на мои вопросы не нашел. Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Что угодно выдержит, если вы купите достаточно серверов под бота.

Comment: А какой меньше ресурсов сервера съест? Например 1 ядро и 1 гиг оперативы, сколько юзеров понянет?

Comment: Меньше ресурсов сервера съест тот, который не на Python.

Comment: К сожалению знаком только с python, исхожу из этого..

Comment: 1) Одновременное обращение тысячи человек - какой то фантастичный сценарий :) Либо у вас количество подписчиков будет исчисляться миллионами... 2) Обращение тысячи человек означает что вам прилетит 1000 строк... По моему это любой современный не то что сервер, а компьютер выдержит. 3) Пишите сами, так по крайней мере сможете понять суть, как все это работает, в общем, там ничего особо сложного нет.